# Passing object sequence as a parameter using Oracle PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to write a PL/SQL function that takes as a parameter 2 arguments. First parameter is an integer and second parameter is an Oracle sequence object.

This function returns a decimal value which is `param1.param2` where `param2` must be the next value of the sequence object taken as parameter.

Example: function `myFc(15,objSq)`. Suppose `objSq.nextVal` is 33 then the returned decimal value must be 15.33

Comment: Hmmm, I've never seen a requirement like this before. Can you share more about it, as I'd be concerned that you're going down the wrong track in solving a problem in this way.

Comment: I agree with David.  You can pass in a string as the name of the sequence like 'schemaname.mysequence' then create a dynamic string that selects the nextval from the sequence using EXEC IMMEDIATE. This is a truly weird thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a little strange. You should always know what sequence you're going to be using and please be aware that a sequence will *never* generate [a gap-free sequence of numbers](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:530735152441), a perfect 1, 2 ..n.

As you don't know an object name you have to use [execute immediate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317), which enables you to use it. You should probably also use [`dbms_assert`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_assert.htm#BABDDEEF) to protect against SQL Injection.

The answer to your question would look something like this:

```
create or replace my_function ( 
                Pnumber in number
              , Psequence in varchar2 ) return number is

   l_nextval number;

begin

   execute immediate '
       select ' || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(Psequence) || '.nextval
         from dual'
         into l_nextval;

   -- Who knows how many decimal places you might need?
   return to_number(Pnumber || '.' || l_nextval, '99.9999');

end;
/
```

**However**, I don't understand why you would want to do this. You obviously know the name of the sequence that you are attempting to use. Instead of using a function you could simply use this information in your calling code:

```
to_number(15 || '.' || sequence_name.nextval, '99.9999')
```

Lastly, as David says in his comment this is a very strange requirement. Are you absolutely certain that this is what you want to be doing? Maybe by explaining *why* you're doing this someone may be able to come up with a better suggestion.

Comment: If you're using a sequence to represent a value on the "right" side (decimal side) of a number, you should probably consider the use of the "CYCLE" option for the sequence. If the sequence is at 9.999, the next number should reset the decimal place to: 0 but the left side of the decimal should increase so that the number after 9.999 is really 10.000.

Comment: @Ben `You should always know what sequence you're going to be using / However, I don't understand why you would want to do this` This is basic indirection. Think of reusability, my friend. Like when you don't want to copy a trigger 7 times (because you shouldn't, but AFAIK you can't attach one trigger to multiple tables) and rather delegate the work to a common stored proc with the varying stuff as input. There are scenarios where you need to use a Sequence you can't hardcode in advance.

Comment: One reason for doing this is db tolerance function, which can be used in liquibase and ORM mappers as a unique for all db vendors (using nextval differs from db to db vendor)